# creating delay while playing multiple Audio files simultaneously using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Outrageous number of similar questions exist here, sadly none did help me.

I am trying to play 3 Audio files simultaneously, one is `.wav` , the other is `.3gp` and the other is `.mp3` . Since the size exceeds more than `1MB` , I cannot use Android `SoundPool` here. So far, everything works well without any error. Here is my code :

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer songPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer voicePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private String song,voice,text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time__date);
    String temp;



    SharedPreferences preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("musicList", MODE_PRIVATE);

    song = preferences1.getString("MUSICONE", "");


    SharedPreferences preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("recordList",MODE_PRIVATE);
    temp = preferences2.getString("VOICEONE","");
    voice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache2/"+temp;


    SharedPreferences preferences3 = getSharedPreferences("TextList",MODE_PRIVATE);
    temp=preferences3.getString("ALARMONE","");
    text=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/"+temp;


    try {
        mp.setDataSource(text);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);

        songPlayer.setDataSource(song);
        songPlayer.prepare();
        songPlayer.setLooping(true);

        voicePlayer.setDataSource(voice);
        voicePlayer.prepare();
        voicePlayer.setLooping(true);



    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
    songPlayer.start();
    voicePlayer.start();
}
```

Now, my query is how do I add a delay to one ore more Audio files, Say If I want to add a delay of `5000` for `voicePlayer` before it loops again?

Comment: "Since the size exceeds more than 1MB , I cannot use Android SoundPool here" where did you find such a constraint?

Comment: The sound files played with SoundPool should not exceed 1 MB.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, my query is how do I add a delay to one ore more Audio files, Say If I want to add a delay of 5000 for `voicePlayer` before it loops again?

You could remove `setLooping` and use an [`OnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) instead. When you get the `onCompletion` callback, use [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) to post a `Runnable` that starts the player again.